# SQL Sentence help select multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, search

I have this setence that select a Product ***NAME*** from my table ***Produto*** and select the quantity from other table named ***Contagens*** where the ***Produto.EANU*** = ***Contagens.PRODUTO*** but I also have some ***QTD*** that are related to ***EANP*** istead of ***EANU*** and I want to them be shown as ***ARM*** instead of ***QTD***.

Is there any way that I can get those 2 sentences in one ?

```
SELECT Produto.NAME, IFNULL(Contagens.QTD ,0) as QTD FROM Produto 
LEFT 
OUTER JOIN Contagens ON Produto.EANU = Contagens.PRODUTO 
ORDER BY NAME

SELECT Produto.NAME, IFNULL(Contagens.QTD ,0) as ARM FROM Produto 
LEFT 
OUTER JOIN Contagens ON Produto.EANP = Contagens.PRODUTO
ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: The first query has the same condition in both parts of the `OR`. Is that intentional?

Comment: edit thanks didnt noticed

Comment: FYI, these are called "queries", not "sentences".

Answer (score 0):

Just join them using aliases:

```
SELECT Produto.NAME, 
       IFNULL(EANU_Contagens.QTD ,0) as QTD, 
       IFNULL(EANP_Contagens.QTD ,0) as ARM
  FROM Produto 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Contagens AS EANU_Contagens ON Produto.EANU = EANU_Contagens.PRODUTO
       LEFT OUTER JOIN Contagens AS EANP_Contagens ON Produto.EANP = EANP_Contagens.PRODUTO
ORDER BY NAME
```

Comment: Didnt work says "#1054 - Coluna 'Contagens.PRODUTO' desconhecida em 'on clause'" but the colunm exists

Comment: @RafaelSousa, sorry forgot to reference by alias. I corrected my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the conditions, and then use `IF` in the `SELECT` list to test which condition was matched.

```
SELECT p.Name, IF(p.EANU = c.PRODUTO, Contagens.QTD, 0) AS QTD, IF(p.EANP = c.PRODUTO, Contagents.QTD, 0) AS ARM
FROM Produto AS p
LEFT JOIN Contagens AS c ON c.PRODUTO IN (p.EANU, p.EANP)
ORDER BY p.Name
```

Comment: didnt work when I use it it doubles the result doesnt get them in 1 row